# Вставить одновременно несколько записей из кода C# в таблицу

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

Подскажите, как можно вставить большое кол-во записей разом из кода C#?

Я знаю, что есть BulkCopy, но есть ли еще варианты?

Есть вариант генерировать VALUES и вставлять по 1000 записей, но не будет ли это медленно? Ведь на сервер может слаться большая строка с запросом(Может я XML здоровенный хочу вставить).

**UPD**

Нашел еще такой вариант: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/nycnet/2012/05/11/one-way-to-insert-many-rows-very-fast-from-your-net-application/

На сервер в процедуру отправляется XML из которого происходит вставка.

По идее это позволяет вставлять свыше 1000 записей, но не пострадает ли производительность?

Comment: с помощью `BulkCopy` я вставлял около 200к записей раз в минуту. Еще вариант `BULK INSERT` из заранее подготовленного файла. Разница по времени в пределах погрешности измерения. Как часто вы собираетесь делать массовую вставку? Если реже чем раз в минуту, то в производительность вы вряд ли упретесь. А вот вставлять строки по одной в цикле через LiNQ запросы, при таком количестве даже не думайте, серверу будет комфортно, но завершения выполнения задачи я так и не дождался, остановил принудительно.

Comment: Скорее всего с `values` ощутимое время будет тратиться на парсинг текста запроса и его компиляцию. Думаю, что вставка из XML будет быстрее `values` (за исключением, возможно, случая, когда вставляется совсем небольшое количество записей), а `BulkCopy` будет быстрее XML-способа.

Answer (score 1):

В SqlCommand можно передать приличный по размеру скрипт, можно даже в параметрами.

Comment: На сколько приличный? Вот например values накладывает ограничение в 1000 записей и вся приличность пропадает... Другое дело, слать xml на с данными для вставки, как я описал в вопросе, но на сколько это быстро?

Comment: Что мешает передать N инструкций insert, в которых будет по 1000 values.
А по существу вопроса, CommandTest может содержать до 2,147,483,647 символов.